# POST requesting randomized names

Tags: php, sql

So i've run into an issue here.

I need to be able to select one of the two radio buttons that this code makes.

```
                        $data = "SELECT * FROM docenten";
                $var = mysqli_query($db, $data);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($var)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->ID . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->Naam . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->Afkorting . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->aanwezigheid . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='select' value='Afwezig,".$row->ID."'>Afwezig <input type='radio' name='select' value='Aanwezig,".$row->ID."'>Aanwezig";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
```

What is does is it gets every person from my database and creates 2 radio buttons for each of the people. but the problem i'm facing right now is is that i can only update one person. As in say 5 people appear in the table i can only select one of the radio buttons because they all have the same name.
Now i tried making the name of all the radio buttons the same name as the ID of the person but that doesn't work

I'm trying to make something like this:

```
                        $data = "SELECT * FROM docenten";
                $var = mysqli_query($db, $data);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($var)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->ID . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->Naam . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->Afkorting . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->aanwezigheid . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='".$ID."' value='Afwezig,".$row->ID."'>Afwezig <input type='radio' name='".$ID."' value='Aanwezig,".$row->ID."'>Aanwezig";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
```

Which i can then call in my server.php

```
if (isset($_POST['ID'])) {
$value = $_POST['ID'];
$arr = explode(",", $value);
$query = "UPDATE docenten SET aanwezigheid = '" . $arr['0'] . "' WHERE ID = '" . $arr[1] . "'";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
    } else {
    array_push($errors, "Oeps er is iets fout gegaan");
    }
```

Sorry if i'm not making any sense i'm really bad at asking these kinds of questions

Comment: Your $_POST['ID'] is not called ID on the name of the input radio

Comment: if you want to allow the selection of multiple people then you probably want a set of checkboxes instead of radio buttons. The whole point of radio buttons is to force the user to choose exactly one item from a set. Checkboxes allow 0 or more items to be selected, at the user's discretion. (Maybe I've misunderstood the situation but that's what it sounds like. I don't really know what the existing radio buttons are actually for, because their names are not in English)

Comment: Remember, if any answer solves your question, mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I can see, you are doing a loop for showing the list. You can use the ID as the name, but you will have to do the same loop while getting the POST.

```
$data = "SELECT * FROM docenten";
$var = mysqli_query($db, $data);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($var)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->ID . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->Naam . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->Afkorting . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->aanwezigheid . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='".$row->ID."' value='Afwezig,".$row->ID."'>Afwezig <input type='radio' name='".$ID."' value='Aanwezig,".$row->ID."'>Aanwezig";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Now you should do the same loop but with:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($var)) {
    if(isset($_POST[$row->ID])) {
        // Do your query
    }
}
```

That would check of the value for each entry is set or not.